# Safe guard Angular 6 code after aot build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

Maybe question looks like foolish one.
I have a Angular 6 Application. I build application using `ng build --aot`
then I have noticed that there is one file linked in my index.html main.js
when I opened it it show all my component code my api call even my api url also.

So can we safe guard this in any way.

I googled it but no satisfactory answer or no answer.

My final solution would be to restrict to open .js file directly on my server.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build angular application, or any web application, static content like .js, .html and other assets are transferred to client browser when he navigates to your app, it is the application itself. There is no way to prevent this, your app would not exist without it. Also urls in your javascript files will be available, otherwise no one, even your app wouldn't know how to connect to your rest endpoint.

You can build your app with `ng build --prod` which *uglifies* your source code so it is harder to read and understand, but the code will be still served to client browser and client can view that file.